# May I initialize a global variable with the result of a function call?

Tags: c++, variables

Is the following code legal?

```
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

int some_global_variable = add(1, 2);

int main() { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Yes. Yes, it is.](http://www.ideone.com/sHtWI)

Static initializers may call functions, as long as they're in scope.

`[dcl.decl]` (2003 wording, 8/2):

> **Initial values can also be specified
>   in a declarator**; initializers are
>   discussed in 8.5 and 12.6.

`[dcl.init]` (2003 wording, 8.5/2):

> Automatic, register, **static**, and
>   external variables of namespace scope
>   **can be initialized by arbitrary
>   expressions involving** literals and
>   **previously declared** variables and
>   **functions**.

(Don't be misled by the lack of the `static` keyword, which has all sorts of meanings. Your variable `myvar` is declared at namespace scope, and thus has *static storage duration*.)

Comment: If you do this, be careful of ordering issues - there is no guarantee of what order static initializers run in when they are in different translation units. If the initializers don't use any other global variables, of course, there's no problem.

Comment: `namespace scope` means "global scope"?