# Is it safe to initialize global const variables, defines?

Tags: c++

Can I initialize global variables and defines like the following code in C++?
If not, could you explain the detailed reason?

I'm in charge of lots of old code, there are much code snippet written like this. How should I reconstruct them safely?

```
// initialize the global variable with the result from a function call
const double g_dbScale = CHelper::GetSystemDPI();

#define DEFAULT_WIDTH       (500 * g_dbScale)
#define DEFAULT_HEIGHT      (200 * g_dbScale)
```

Comment: Yes you can do that. But why not use `const double` variables for DEFAULT_WIDTH and DEFAULT_HEIGHT also?

Comment: @M.M these are old code of others, I hate such code. But there are plenty of such usage.

Comment: Trick question - you can't initialize a define.

Comment: why did I get 2 down votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depend on your funcion `CHelper::GetSystemDPI();`
If this function does not reference any other global varialbe or some other issue it should be ok.

C ++ does not guarantee the initialization sequence of global variables for different compilation units.

relate to [may-i-initialize-a-global-variable-with-the-result-of-a-function-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337426/may-i-initialize-a-global-variable-with-the-result-of-a-function-call)