# Why does the following snippet speed up the code?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I was solving the [Search Insert Position](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-insert-position/description/) problem on LeetCode. The following code takes almost 9ms to run all test cases.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int searchInsert(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int lo = 0, hi = nums.size() - 1;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            if (target < nums[mid]) {
                hi = mid - 1;
            } else if (target > nums[mid]){
                lo = mid + 1;
            } else {
                return mid;
            }
        }
        return lo;
    }
};
```

When I checked out other people's top answers, I found a strange code snippet. When I copy-paste the snippet into my answer, the same code above takes only 4ms, which is faster than almost 99% of other solutions. Can anyone explain the speed up? The snippet is the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static vector<int> nums=[](){
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    return vector<int>{};
}();
```

Comment: Some sites offer bogus knowledge. Some don't. The so called _competitive programming_ is bogus knowledge imho. You are far better off reading one these  [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). That being said it is unclear what the problem is as there is no problem to begin with.

Comment: It's just a trick to run `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);` before `main` is entered. Those two lines turn off synchronization between C++ standard streams `cin` and `cout`, and C standard streams `stdin` and `stdout`; on some systems, this improves performance of reading and writing standard streams. Apparently, most of the time in your case is spent not on actually solving the problem, but on I/O before and after.

Comment: For anyone who has doubts on the lambda initialization: I found out that static global variables can be initialized by function calls which I used to take as illegal, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337426/may-i-initialize-a-global-variable-with-the-result-of-a-function-call) for sure. In addition, lambda is called not just defined(the parenthesis). Thank you all guys.

Comment: The author apparently picked an arbitrary global (or in this case, file scope) variable, and added a lambda-call initializer just to call some completely unrelated initialization functions. Personally, I think this "pattern" should not be used outside of voluntary obfuscation or [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)!

Comment: The time difference indicates that you spend most of the time doing I/O. Those  lines have no influence on the algorithm as such.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This snippet is made to "improve performance" but for a cost. I'll explain:

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

This disables the synchronization of C and C++ standard streams. By default they're synced to allow mixing C and C++ I/O streams (e.g. cout and printf would work written in a C++ file).

```
cin.tie(NULL);
```

This unties cin from cout. Again, by default they're tied to make cout appear before cin (i.e. output flushes before input) so you can make for example the following:

```
cout << "Number: ";
cin >> number;
```

When you untie them you might get to the input(cin) before getting the output (cout) flushed.

These couple lines help to make code run faster but at the cost previously explained. So use with caution.

References: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fast-io-for-competitive-programming

Comment: Can you add the references that confirm this to your answer?

Comment: Done. Thanks @Chiel

Comment: This is already a good answer, but it would be even better if you also explained what's happening with the initialization from a lambda.

Comment: Didn't this also loose thread-safety of cout?

Comment: Yes. Different outputs interleave most of the time, although no data races will occur. @MikeMB

Comment: @Abdallah: "although no data races will occur." Are you sure? I haven't checked the standard, but cppreference.com days race freedom is only ensured as long as `std::ios::sync_with_stdio` is true

Comment: @Sneftel I found out that static global variables can be initialized by function calls which I used to take as illegal, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337426/may-i-initialize-a-global-variable-with-the-result-of-a-function-call) for sure. In addition, lambda is called not just assignment. Thank you all guys.

Comment: @MikeMB you're right. I understood that point wrongly. And I also can't find information about data races when `sync_with_stdio` is disabled...

Comment: "Concurrent access to a synchronized (27.5.3.4) standard iostream object’s formatted and unformatted input (27.7.2.1) and output (27.7.3.1) functions or a standard C stream by multiple threads shall not result in a data race (1.10). [Note: Users must still synchronize concurrent use of these objects and streams by multiple threads if they wish to avoid interleaved characters. — end note ]" (iostreams.objects.overview; 27.4.1/4 in N3797)