What is the magic behind sync_with_stdio(false)
From the following post:
Using scanf() in C++ programs is faster than using cin?
I know that after setting sync_with_stdio(false), cin can read faster. My question is: why?
Previously I thought that after calling sync_with_stdio(false), the system might create a buffer to decrease the stdin communication times: when a read request comes, the system might read several characters into a buffer before doing the parse. However, I realized this is not true since cin will block and wait for the customer to input characters one by one. So this means that no matter sync_with_stdio(false) is being called or not, the system has to wait the user's input.
Then I thought that after calling sync_with_stdio(false), the stdin might change from blocked reading to unblocked reading. However, I tried to write the following code:
#include <fcntl.h>


int main()
{
    auto saved_flags = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL);
    std::cout << saved_flags << std::endl;

    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    saved_flags = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL);
    std::cout << saved_flags << std::endl;
}


And the system output the same number, so this means that sync_with_stdio(false) does not change the flag of stdin at all.
From https://www.quora.com/Is-cin-cout-slower-than-scanf-printf/answer/Aditya-Vishwakarma the author mentioned:

Performance of cin/cout can be slow because they need to keep
themselves in sync with the underlying C library. This is essential if
both C IO and C++ IO is going to be used.

But it is too abstract to me. Can you tell me what is the real logic that causes the cin became faster after calling sync_with_stdio(false)?
Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48368142/4342498

Don't tag other languages.

Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio

You seem to think that sync_with_stdio will have an effect on fcntl. It only has an effect on the buffer shared between C IO and C++ IO.

There is nothing stopping other code from calling C I/O functions, affecting the state of streams, buffers, etc etc. By forcing C++ streams to synchronise with C streams (e.g. so two operations on a file produce the same effects in the same order) almost every operation on C++ streams must check state of the associated C streams, wait for actions to complete, etc (all things that C I/O functions don't have to do). Doing those checks means either overhead (CPU cycles) or observable delay waiting for operations to complete, etc.  Turning off synchronisation reduces or eliminates all that.

It is a line that is most often used in competitive coding. I've almost never seen it used in production code and it is blindly copied in competitive coding. (Hoping it will shave a few tenth's of milliseconds of the execution time). But other than that is as @Peter says it works.

@PepijnKramer  I've never seen it in production code either (and, frankly, would be concerned if I did).   Even in hard realtime systems, there are bigger fish to fry (algorithm design and selection, come to mind) than trying to shave a few milliseconds of execution time related to I/O.

@Peter Absolutely... not to mention that this kind of optimization is not threadsafe and on competitive coding sites the time gained is way below the accuracy in which competitive coding sites can measure the performance of the code. So it is meaningless in that respect too... and another reason I think competitive coding should not exist.

By blocked and unblocked reading, you think it talks about reads (and also writes) to the actual file (terminal).
No
It only refers to the buffer that C IO and C++ IO use when synced. When synced, they will both use the same buffer with C++ IO being cautious to avoid data races. But the flags on the actual file (terminal) are unaffected.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio

In practice, this means that the synchronized C++ streams are unbuffered, and each I/O operation on a C++ stream is immediately applied to the corresponding C stream's buffer. This makes it possible to freely mix C++ and C I/O.
In addition, synchronized C++ streams are guaranteed to be thread-safe

