# Can a smart pointer be forward declared and initialized separately?

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

I'm trying to learn how to use smart pointers in Cpp, and I'm running into a roadblock; I want to declare my variables as say unique_ptr in one part of my code, possibly as a class member or part of a namespace, then initialize/"make_unique" elsewhere in my code. I've read quite a few questions about smart pointers, and incomplete type information, but I'm not sure I'm fully understanding. This is the last resource I read; [Incomplete types and shared_ptr / unique_ptr](http://web.archive.org/web/20140903193346/http://home.roadrunner.com/%7Ehinnant/incomplete.html)

This is my toy code I'm trying to get working. 'v1' works as expected, on a single line. 'v2' Is what i'm trying to make work

```
std::unique_ptr<glm::vec3>v1 = std::make_unique<glm::vec3>(); //Works as expected
std::unique_ptr<glm::vec3>v2; //Declare a unique_ptr here, but i don't want to allocate any memory for it yet...

//do things i need to do before memory is allocated to v2

v2 = std::make_unique<glm::vec3>(); //...NOW I want to allocate memory for v2 and prepare it to be used
```

These are the errors i get from VS2017, both referring to the line where i make_unique v2:

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

error C2371: 'templategl::v2': redefinition; different basic types

EDIT: Yes, I should have provided a better example. And in creating one, I answered my own question. The revised code follows;

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct vec3 {
    vec3() { x = y = z = 1.f; }
    vec3(float val) { x = y = z = val; }
    float x, y, z;
};

//smart pointers in a namespace...
namespace smptrns {
    std::unique_ptr<vec3>v0; //will be init in a namespace function
    std::unique_ptr<vec3>v1 = std::make_unique<vec3>(); //Works as expected
    std::unique_ptr<vec3>v2; //Declare a unique_ptr here, but i don't want to allocate any memory for it yet...
    //v2 = std::make_unique<vec3>(); //...NOW I want to allocate memory for v2 and prepare it to be used
    //^This is my problem, initializing v2 in namespace outside of a function.
    void initpntr() {
        v0 = std::make_unique<vec3>(); //Works
    }
}

int main() {
    smptrns::initpntr();
    smptrns::v2 = std::make_unique<vec3>(5.f); //Also works
    std::cout << smptrns::v0->x << "\t" << smptrns::v1->x << "\t" << smptrns::v2->x << "\n";
}
```

I was trying to initialize v2 *outside of a function*, fixed by either assigning to it from a function in the namespace, or within my main loop and accessing it directly with the :: operator. As I'm trying to reserve memory *at runtime*, this makes sense.

Comment: `std::make_unique<glm::vec3>()` requires definition of `glm::vec3` (that you should have via some include) and `#include <memory>`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ETYWpe). Please, provide a _complete verifiable example_.

Comment: What is the context of the statement `v2 = std::make_unique<glm::vec3>();`?  Is it within a function?  If not then please see, e.g. [`"Code outside functions"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313450/code-outside-functions/11313473#11313473).

Comment: @G.M. Maybe, a more relevant question is [May I initialize a global variable with the result of a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6337426/580083).

Comment: You've probably jumped to a conclusion somewhere and are now asking for help down the wrong road. Forget what you think is causing your compiler error; instead ask about your compiler error, backed up with a [mre].

Comment: Your first error suggests that you wrote this assignment outside of a function. The second error follows from your writing it outside of a function making it a declaration of an `int`. Get a good book and start at the beginning.

Comment: Now that this is reopened, please post your answer **as an answer** and remove it from your question ... thanks ...

Comment: @Jesse You really should do what's suggested above and post your solution as an actual answer, and then set it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, when my unique_ptr variable is declared elsewhere, std::make_unique needed to be called *within a function*, and not in a global or namespace scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a global or namespace scope object without initializing it using `extern` keyword:

```
extern std::unique_ptr<glm::vec3> v2; // Declaration only.
// ...
std::unique_ptr<glm::vec3> v2 = std::make_unique<glm::vec3>(); // Declaration and definition with initialization.
```